# if a book has a $25 retail price and a 0.55% discount, the price to the bookstore would be $11.25. what is the formula of finding 4.50$

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula

It is based on the Retail Price and the Standard Discount Rate. For example, if a book has a $25 retail price and a 0.55% discount, the price to the bookstore would be $11.25. 
how to found that 11.25$ ?

```
i tried something like 0.55 * 25 = 13.75 but i want to find left 45%.
```

i am doing in excel   `D3(0.55) * D4(25)* 100` through this i can find the right answer but i want to find the 45% which left.

my retail price is 25$ discount rate is 0.55% so now tell me the formula i want to find  45% . if i change me discount value answer should be change.

plz help me 
remember  i want the formula for excel.

Comment: Wait, is your discount rate `0.55%` now? That is a very small discount. Or did you mean `55%`?

Comment: Please take a basic math class. This calculation is routinely taught to children around the age of 10 in the US, and our education system isn't very well respected world-wide. Also, we're not going to write your Excel formula for you. We'll give you the information you need to do the math, but you can put it into Excel yourself. If you can't do that, you're not learning anything. *Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, and you feed him for a lifetime.* Learn to fish, instead of begging for a meal.

Comment: yes means 55%..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea where the `25` came from in your formula, but the equation you want is:

```
10*(1 - 0.55) = 10*0.45 = 4.5
```

Comment: Better would be *Price * ((100-Discount) / 100.0)*, or `10 * ((100-55) / 100.0) = 10 * 0.45 = 4.5`

Comment: @KenWhite That could be better, but I opted with the simpler version, since I know he has the percent already as a decimal, because there are a couple of places in his question with `0.55`.

Comment: Yeah, except the next question is going to be *What if the discount is 33.3%?*.

Comment: my retail price is 25$ discount rate is 0.55% so now tell me the formula i want to find  45% . if i change me discount value answer should be change.

Comment: @UsmanAli Okay, you said the retail price was $10 in your question, not $25. If you have 55% and want to find the remainder it's just `100% - 55% = 45%`. If you have it as a decimal, like `0.55`, then it is `(1 - 0.55) = 0.45`.

Comment: @KenWhite Yeah, I thought he understood that part because he mentioned both `55%` and `0.55` in the question and `% "percent"` literally means `per hundred` or `/100`.

Comment: @UsmanAli `11.25` would be a `55%` discount, ***not*** `0.55%`. The equation is the same, but, of course, change 10 to 25: `25*(1 - 0.55) = 11.25`.

Comment: now read the question i edit that. retail price is 25 and discount is 0.55% so according to that 11.25 is the correct ans which i want.

Comment: @UsmanAli Well that is pretty goofy, because a `0.55%` discount would only bring the price down to `25*(1 - 0.0055) = 24.8625` ***not*** `11.25`. I've also never heard of a retail store doing a discount of less than one percent.

Comment: You do realize you've now become the hand-holder here, and that this is never going to end?

Comment: yeh exactly i got 24.86  but i want 11.25  so what should i do? tell me what i need to change.

Comment: @UsmanAli You don't need to change anything. That is the correct answer for a `0.55%` discount from `$25`.

Comment: thanks bro i have done :)

Comment: 25 is retail price + 55% discount

Answer (score 0):

Where did the 25 come from in your formula?

What you want is:

Retail Price * (100 - discount)/100

or

$10 * (1 - 0.55)

Comment: my retail price is 25$ discount rate is 0.55% so now tell me the formula i want to find  45% . if i change me discount value answer should be change.

Comment: now read the question i edit that. retail price is 25 and discount is 0.55% so according to that 11.25 is the correct ans which i want.